# Debugger stops on a line using webstorm when debugging mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 7.0.3 and have just installed mongoose in my nodejs application.

When I start debugging, I get the debugger stopping on the following line:

```
Mongoose.prototype.createConnection = function () {..}
```

I then in WebStorm press F5 (resume program) and then the program runs.

So how do I prevent the debugger from stopping at the above line?

Note that there are no debug points at that line.

Answer (score 1):

seems to be the known issue - [WEB-8174](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8174). This is actually V8 problem (http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2825). You can try running node with -nolazy flag (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8174#comment=27-667984) - it might help

Comment: Thanks lena. It has helped slightly that it is only stopping on a couple of lines whereas before it got to the point where it would stop (as though it had a debug point) about 6 times in different locations.